# Store user submitted apostrophe in database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

This script allows the user to store a word in the database:

*submit.php* script:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Sentance: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

*welcome.php* script :

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
echo $_POST["word"];

mysql_connect("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");
mysql_select_db("xxxx");
$word1 = $_POST['word'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO words VALUES ('$word1');");
?>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that if a user submitted a word containing an apostrophe, it doesn't get stored in the database.

for example word:

```
hello'world
```

doesn't get stored because it contains an apostrophe..

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Read up on Mysql Injection, there're plenty of materials in the web, also consider reading the warnings in php's manual, they're pretty important.

Comment: Try with `$word1 = addslashes($_POST['word']);` Btw you are using a deprecated database API. Switch to MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: @php_nub_qq To add to your comment, I suggest to start by actually reading the php manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wide open to sql injection.  First of all, I strongly recommend that you stop using `mysql_` family of functions, they are deprecated.  If you must, then make to escape user input.  However I strongly recommend that you use `PDO`:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost,port=3306,username=user,password=pass', 'user', 'pass');
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO words VALUES (:word)");
$stmt->bindParam(':word', $word);
$word = $_POST['word'];
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I would have stopped using MySQL_ if PDO wasn't so complicated. thanks for your help

Comment: @user3125898 PDO is not complicated at all.  Spend 20 minutes looking at the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) - there are examples for everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, you should be sanitizing your input, and don't use mysql_query as its deprecated.

Look at [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) for escaping these very bad characters.

Then look at [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) to replace mysql_query.

The code as you have it now leaves you open to injection.